# How do I disable the access denied message when trying to do cross scripting into an iframe?

Tags: jquery, xss

I have an iframe that points to a website ie.

```
<iframe src='http://www.fish.com/' id='fish'>
```

I have a html on my local pc that tries to click a button in the iframe:

```
alert ( $('#fish').contents().find('#myButton').length );
```

I have enabled cross site scripting in my browser and lowered security to the max. I still get access denied errors. I have tried in IE6, IE8, and Firefox. How can I remove this restriction? I am trying to test something, and understand the risks etc.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/RSbja/

Using the exact code above.

Answer (score 2):

**Firefox** needs the option `signed.applets.codebase_principal_support` set to `true` (about:config).

**Chrome** needs to get started with `--disable-web-security`

**IE** needs the option `allow cross-domain access (...)` under `Extras -> Security`

---

Those options will disable the security check for cross-domain access on XHR objects and iframes.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle, I get an access denied error still even after setting the above options.